# Rounding issues storing java.util.Date into MySQL datetime

Tags: mysql, hibernate, datetime

MySQL DB column:

```
PLANNING_DATE datetime
```

Java field:

```
private java.util.Date planningDate;
```

Hibernate mapping:

```
<property name="planningDate" column="PLANNING_DATE" type="timestamp" not-null="true"/>
```

The problem:
`PLANNING_DATE` in MySQL DB does not always match `planningDate` field. Sometimes, it gets an offset of 1 second. Is this a rounding issue?

Comment: Why don't you use a `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: I need to store the time info as well: hours, minutes, seconds.

Comment: `java.sql.Timestamp` has a time component.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I think it's because in MySQL >= 5.6.4 they changed DATETIME to truncate fractional seconds by default. I updated our table schemas to use the new DATETIME(6). I'll check if this was indeed the cause.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html

EDIT: Actually, DATETIME in MySQL >= 5.6.4 (which is equivalent to DATETIME(0)) rounds to seconds precision, as opposed to DATE in Oracle which truncates. Added a custom Hibernate type to do truncation instead of rounding and the problem was solved.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Can you please share the customisation code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about either MySql or Hibernate, but here goes…

A) You probably should be using java.sql.Date. It is a thin subclass of java.util.Date, meant fir use with JDBC.

B) The [MySql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fractional-seconds.html) do mention that their date-time types do not store the fractional part of a second. So perhaps there is rounding happening. But the docs mention truncation.